# Performing animation in UI5

Tags: css-animations, sapui5

I am trying to animate an image(id is register1) in ui5. I have tried using using the animate feature of jQuery. But it does not seem to work.

```
    var a = this.getView().byId("register1");
    a.animate.css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0});
    a.animate.css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 0.0});
    a.animate({visible:'true'},"slow");
    a.animate({visible:'false'},"slow");
    a.animate({visible:'true'},"slow");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function 'byId' does not give you a jQuery-object, which is required to use 'animate'

try to use

```
var $a = $(this.getView().byId("register1").getDomRef());
$a.animate.css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0});
$a.animate.css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 0.0});
$a.animate({visible:'true'},"slow");
$a.animate({visible:'false'},"slow");
$a.animate({visible:'true'},"slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

As herrlock wrote, but instead of `getDomRef()` and then getting the jQuery object of it, you can also use the `$()` function, which is available on all UI5 controls. 
And assuming the code is inside a Controller (the `this.getView()` hints at this), you can also use `this.byId()`.

So instead of
`$(this.getView().byId("register1").getDomRef());`
it is:
`this.byId("register1").$()`

Not much different, but a bit less cryptic. :-)

If this does not work, make sure that the HTML element does exist at the time when this code is executed!